# "Kept back" packages for update , want to uninstall unity?

Tags: 16.04, unity, package-management, updates, uninstall

Here is the problem, today i started updating my ubuntu 16.04 laptop, to my surprise i got some packages that are marked as "Kept back", here are these packages

```
compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default libcompizconfig0  libdecoration0
```

After some googling i tried to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` i got some info on the kept back packages, like how many are there, how much memory will they use, the standard stuff and after that, the surprise i got

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:  ubuntu-desktop unity unity-tweak-tool
```

is this normal? i mean uninstall `ubuntu-desktop unity` ??? wont that uninstall my DE ???

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I decided not to proceed with the update. There's something wrong going on...

Comment: This happened to me as well.  Unity and ubuntu-desktop were removed.

Comment: It is not normal. You are right. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity for how to revert back.

Answer (score 2):

You were more observant than me, as I just happily removed Unity using `apt-get dist-upgrade`!
Sure enough it was gone after I rebooted, and `apt-get install -f unity` was also rejected.
I had to install `aptitude` then `aptitude install unity`, which undid the damage caused by `dist-upgrade`.

`dist-upgrade` is still wanting to remove `unity` though.

Comment: I wasn't able to reinstall unity due to a missing dependency.

Comment: To conclude, the aptitude solution to this problem which I promoted, has had no knock-on effects for me and now dist-upgrade has finally happily ran and updated without needing to remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The following steps fixed it for me:

1. Right-click on desktop and open a terminal
2. Execute `sudo aptitude install unity`
3. Answer the first question with "no"
4. Then confirm the downgrade of packages
5. After the operation finished, reboot with `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm what ever was the problem is now resolved. Today i was able to upgrade with no issues.

Comment: I'm glad they fixed this bug in one day.