# Ubuntu TaskBar is gone. Launcher is missing

Tags: launcher, taskbar

I recently updated (Feb 15, 2018) my Ubuntu 16.04 from the software manager. I don't remember what programs got updated, now my taskbar & launcher is gone.

Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried everything that's available from the internet, but none works.

Will upgrading to 17.10 fix my problem? I don't want to do fresh install from the start again :(

Comment: I've tried sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y, it doesn't work.

Comment: If this is what happened to me today, it uninstalled unity, so there is no way to get the launcher back without fixing the system. And there is a missing dependency (which is why it got un-installed)

Comment: I've tried that too. The screen did flicker for a second to have the taskbar appear, but it's gone as soon as it appeared.

Comment: Do you think upgrading to 17.10 will fix the problem? I'm tempted to do that.

Comment: I wouldn't install 17.10. It's a short term OS that expires in July 2018 . I'd wait a day or three for Ubuntu 16.04 bug fix to come out. Just dual boot into Windows and surf the web from there until a fix comes out.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution. apt-get fails to be able to handle the situation, but aptitude can handle it.

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

Note that the first solution offered by aptitude doesn't correct the problem, because that chooses not to install the package. I had to select no the first time, and then aptitude offered a second solution of downgrading the compiz packages that caused all the problems. The downgrade fixes the dependency problem, and then ubuntu-desktop and unity are reinstalled.

Comment: it says command not found.

Comment: @ramster: sudo apt-get install aptitude

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers on different questions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006633/480481). It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.