# What did you guys just DO! Updates to both my 16.04 environs killed the desktops!

Tags: updates, launcher, statusbar

I just had updates run automatically in my 16.04 test and 16.04 live environments and they killed the desktops after I rebooted them! No launcher, no status bar at top. I know they are running, I can left click on desktop to get to settings, but there is no way to closes that once it is open!
Provide restore please!

Comment: See the answer to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity?noredirect=1#comment1629448_1006621 for a temp fix.