# Panel and Launcher are missing in 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher, panel

Previously suggested answers here have not restored the menu bar and launcher.  I've run many updates, enabled the Unity plugin, and scoured Google for commands to restore these items, but with no luck.  Desktop icons appear, however.

The compiz-core version installed is the one referenced in the similar question suggested here.  I installed aptitude and ran the commands to install ubuntu-desktop, and while they appeared to run, they actually downloaded 0B of data and didn't install anything.

Edit 2:  This was marked as a duplicate of [2/15/18 compiz update broke unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity) - I should specify that I have taken all steps outlined in the answers on that question, and my desktop still has not been restored.  Specifically, when I run the command to install Unity, it tells me Unity is already installed.

Comment: If duplicate doesn't apply, try this answer instead then: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing/1007213#1007213

Comment: That looked familiar, but I tried it again just to be sure.  No luck.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))