# Black unity launcher and icons

Tags: unity, launcher, themes

on Ubuntu 16.04 all icons and launcher are black. tried changing the theme/icons still same problem.

[image: Screenshot]

I did nothing new, it happened right after I booted up like I normally do.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me.. also: logging in as a guest works fine..

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1007213/480481

Comment: This happened for me immediately after upgrading to Unity 7.4.5 which was recently back-ported for 16.04.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer exactly but a workaround.

1. Install **Unity Tweak Tool** (`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`)
2. **Launcher** tab | **Appearance** section
3. Set *Colour* to *Custom*

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Do you know if there is an official bug report?

Comment: Sorry I haven’t followed it up, but since Unity will be gone in 18.04 it hardly seems worth the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem after an upgrade.  It was easily fixed by just changing my desktop wallpaper image, which refreshed the launcher icons.

Comment: My wallpaper is automatically changed every day. This definitely does not work for me.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset unity with this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity
```

if not working, reset the options of unity in 
`~/.config/compiz-1/`