# Launcher and menu bar no longer visible after Mar 2/2018 update

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, compiz

I realize this gets reported a fair amount but I've searched as much as I can and nothing appears to be helping. After doing an update last night, I logged in today and cannot see the launcher or menu bar. When I open a terminal window, the title bar at the top is cut off, so I suspect that there might be something scaling-related. It could be:

1. that the launcher and menu bar are no longer there
2. the launcher and menu bar are there, but beyond the borders of the laptop screen.

When I get to the login screen, I can see the menu bar with the time, battery display, wifi, etc.

When I log in to a guest account, the launcher and menu bar appear.

Here are the things that I've tried so far:

1. ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   sudo apt-get install unity
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```
2. ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   setsid unity
   ```

   (when I run these steps, I get a brief resize of the desktop, then it seems stuck on "unity7 start/running, process 8299")
3. ```
   mv ~/.config ~/.config_backup
   ```
4. ```
   rm -rf .compiz-1
   ```
5. ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   setsid unity
   ```
6. ```
   dconf reset /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor
   ```
7. ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   dconf-editor
   ```

   open path com -> ubuntu -> user-interface
   cannot change the scale factor, it doesn't allow me to enter a numeric value
8. ```
   unity --reset (screen briefly resizes, then goes back to "normal")
   ```
9. ```
   initctl restart unity-panel-service
   ```
10. The steps given here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeCs_gIey6c although I don't get the dialog boxes about "resolving conflicts"

Everything has been followed with a reboot.

Comment: I can try those steps, but it's from 2016 and I don't know what version of compiz to install. I did attempt the steps to reinstall unity, to no avail.

Comment: Someone else recently had a problem with Ubuntu Updates. I see you haven't tried this simple solution yet: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update/1007213#1007213

Comment: That's actually in point 4, but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: I should have noticed earlier but you didn't try: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` from the Q&A with 1,000 upvotes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: I have the exact same problems including lack of alt tab and and notice that guest account is fine. see also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386528&page=2
and https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/665349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK Guys, I have found the solution posted in another forum and it works for me and at least two others - very simple. Open a terminal by right clicking on the background then type in this command:
sudo -r ~/.cache
then reboot.

Comment: This did indeed work. Thanks Erica!
Actually, I had to type in "sudo rm -R ~/.cache" but it nonetheless worked anyways.

Comment: @lengthy_preamble since the command provided isn't the command you used and you accepted it I think it would be wise to edit this answer with the command that you actually used. Although to be honest I'm baffled that this worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please try removing `.cache` directory on Home:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache
```

Comment: executing this command and then rebooting fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

As per this [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update/1007213#1007213), try:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
sudo reboot
```

Your step #4 isn't exactly the same thing. For example:

```
rick@alien:~$ locate ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
/home/rick/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
/home/rick/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/done_upgrades
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ rm -rf .compiz-1 # Your step 4)
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ locate ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
/home/rick/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
/home/rick/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/done_upgrades
```

The `compiz` files in question are still there.

Comment: Hello WinEunuuchs2Unix, I tried the above step exactly as written and unfortunately there has been no change, even with a reboot. Oddly enough, I've noticed that I can't resize the borders of any windows or even alt-tab. Very strange.

Comment: @lengthy_preamble That user's update was dated Feb 16/2018 so it could be your update is a different problem altogether. The lack of `Alt`+`Tab` support and window resizing was not mentioned in other posts that I can recall.

Comment: Thank you for trying. For the time being, I have created a new user and hopefully I can get enough work done that way. Hopefully someone will have some other suggestions, though...

Comment: @lengthy_preamble The new user account (or a guest session) is the one thing in common I've seen working in other posts. So there are certainly similarities. I'll keep looking...