# Missing menu, application bar and windows buttons -16.04 116

Tags: menu-bar

Not sure what happened, if it is related to some level of upgrade or something else, but I can no longer access/see the menu and applications bar. I can't also minimize, move or adjust size of any window.

I have tried pretty much all suggestions that google presents on a search for similar issues: stop/start unity, remove .compiz, remove .config, dconf reset -f /org/compiz.....

The only think I can think now is to re-install ubuntu, but before I try I was wonder if anyone has any other suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In case you haven't already tried it: The accepted answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update/1007213#1007213 fixed it for me

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for replying.

Yes I did try that but no success....

Comment: Hi,
Re-installed ubuntu, it might have been OTT but nothing else worked...