# Terminal and all icons missing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have been using ubuntu for quite sometime now and haven't ever faced this situation. All my icons are missing including the terminal. ctrl+Alt+T does not bring up the terminal, right clicking does not show any dropdown either. Most of the answers that I found were wrt to unity and cases where terminal was present. 
I am using ubuntu 16.04

Any solutions as to how this can be fixed are most welcomed.

Comment: I am not aware of that. Is there a way to check?

Comment: So no not using CCSM. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: Is the screen completely blank or is the dash bar at the top and the launcher on the left still there?

Comment: Yes, blank screen. No launcher on the left.

Comment: Okay, you can get to a terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 or CTRL+ALT+F1. Then, sign in with your username and password so you can run commands. Then, see the following answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1007213/167115 Please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Unity is a Compiz plugin. You may need to install `compizconfig-settings-manager` but this package is in the Universe repository so you may need to enable this repository. I can help you with this so please let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: Terminal not coming up by using either of the above mentioned commands.

Comment: It should take you to a new black screen with a login prompt. Try CTRL+ALT+F3 or CTRL+ALT+F4 Type in your username and then press ENTER and then type in your password and then press ENTER.

Comment: Yeah that worked out. Now I should follow up on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update/1007213#1007213 ?

Comment: @mchid followed up on the link, but the problem persists.

Comment: Okay, try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/286349/167115

Comment: Also, this might fix the problem: `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority`

Comment: Following up on https://askubuntu.com/a/286349/167115 it returns error: could not connect ubuntu connectionissues. Tried sudo systemctl restart network-manager is not working to fix the connection issue.

Comment: This may be a failure to connect to the x-session. Try running `export DISPLAY=:0` before you run `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ ` and `unity --reset-icons &disown` and then, run: `sudo systemctl restart lightdm` This should take you back to your regular login screen.