# Unity Top Bar and Launcher disappeared Feb 24/2018

Tags: 16.04, unity, compiz

I had run `apt upgrade` a couple of days back, and restarted my PC a while after, when the top bar and the launcher disappeared.
I have tried all the following solutions, but none of them worked:

1. [Reinstall ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04)
2. [Removed Unity entirely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651013/can-i-remove-unity-now-and-how) and reinstalled it again.
3. [Using `dconf reset` and `setsid unity`](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2238678)
4. [Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/290376#290376)
5. Running `unity --reset` or `initctl restart unity-panel-service` just flashes the top bar and the launcher and disappears again.
6. [Removing the compiz-1 folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801450/top-menu-bar-and-launcher-disappeared-after-updating-yesterday-16-04-lts)
7. Removing the .compiz folder

EDIT:

8. [All upgrades installed + compiz-core is already the newest version(20170630)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity)

I have been searching for solutions for days now without any luck. Although the above solutions have been working for others, none of them seem to work for me. How do I fix this?

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Please check out the duplicate posted by @N0rbert and let us know if it fixes it or not.

Comment: The issue persists. On going through related questions, I came across https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006592/kept-back-packages-for-update-want-to-uninstall-unity, where on running apt-get dist-upgrade, the 'The following packages will be REMOVED:  ubuntu-desktop unity unity-tweak-tool' warning was triggered. This did NOT happen in my case, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @N0rbert Can you read OP comment above and consider retracting your VTC or asking OP for additional details about duplicate qualification please?

Comment: What kernel version are you using? `uname -r` will report it. Can you boot to an earlier kernel version in Grub's **Advanced Options** menu to see if another version works?

Comment: `uname -r` gives `4.4.0-116-generic`. I will try booting to an earlier kernel version now, if possible, and see if that fixes anything.
EDIT: Booted to 4.4.0-112-generic. The issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Yesterday I tried advice from WinEunuuchs2Unix answer [in ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update) and it fixed the problem in my case.

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
```

I have tried to remove it before, but nothing changed. And just after mesa downgrade, and then removing compiz config files Unity panels come back to their usual places. But I still can't understand what was the main cause of crashing.

Comment: How did you downgrade mesa?

Comment: I download debs from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2/+build/13231714 and then organized local repo for mesa. And then sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install libgbm1=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 ...

Comment: I made local repo to prevent broken dependenses, but somebody just used dpkg -i pack_name.deb

Comment: Packages: sudo apt-get install libgbm1=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libgl1-mesa-dri=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libegl1-mesa=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libwayland-egl1-mesa=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libgl1-mesa-dev=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libgl1-mesa-glx=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libglapi-mesa=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 mesa-common-dev=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libosmesa6=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libglapi-mesa:i386=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libgles2-mesa=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 libosmesa6:i386=17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

Comment: Just downgraded mesa using the above instructions , and ran `rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*`. Still no luck. I have also tried downgrading compiz-core-abiversion-20170630 to [compiz-core-abiversion-20160415](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/compiz-core/download) and removed compiz config files. No luck again.

Comment: Check for unity and ubuntu-desktop packages, they may be removed while mesa downgrade. If so sudo apt-get install unity ubuntu-desktop

Comment: If you boot in recovery do have panels in low graphic mode with minimum screen resolution?  In my case I had panels in this mode, but very low resolution and compiz loads CPU for 90%.

Comment: And one more detail, I'm using HWE: sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04

Comment: unity and ubunu-desktop were not removed. And haven't tried booting in recovery. Will check soon.